# Embeddable mp3 player with time navigation in the audio

Tags: javascript, mp3, media-player

Do you know how you can leave a comment on a YouTube video specifying a certain time in the video (i.e. 16:59) and when the comment is submitted, the time specified turns into a link, and when clicked, will take you to that time in the video?

Well, I'd like to implement that functionality except with mp3s.

I want to have some kind of mp3 player with links below the player of say, chapters, that will help me navigate to certain parts of an mp3.

What kind of Web technology will help me get this functionality?

Comment: There is no special 'web technology' for this. Youtube's video player simply looks for the timecode in the anchor part of the url and jumps to that position in the video. An equivalent "technology" for an mp3 would essentially be idenctical, except it's an audio player, not video.

Comment: Just get the HTML anchor, using AS3 or JS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web technology that you'll need:

- [fragment identifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

I would recommend using some library for HTML5 audio with Flash fallback, like this:

- [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/)

If you're using jQuery then those plugins might help you:

- [BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)
- [Hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/)